# visualize the centroid on the point cloud by pcl

Tags: point-cloud-library, centroid

I find the centroid over the point clouds by using PCL, I want to know how to visualize these centroid on the point clouds.

Comment: That pretty much depends on what you're using for visualization. Moreover, what did you try so far?

Comment: You could draw a small sphere where the centroid was calculated to be